# Java JTableHeader styling

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

I want to accomplish a similar header style to this:

[image]

How could this be accomplished?

All i have so far is:

```
    JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
    header.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(239, 235, 230));
    header.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(107, 109, 107));
    header.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 26));
```

Comment: `TableHeader` supports renderers

Answer (score 2):

`TableHeader` supports `TableCellRenderer` for rendering the headers.

Take a look at [`TableHeader#setDefaultRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html#setDefaultRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29) and [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)